# Add rate limit to public api returning customer status (exists, not-exist) against email

Tags: node.js, api, cloudflare, rate-limiting, express-rate-limit

I have `api` which will return user status i.e exists or not exists in the shop against email. Now the challenge here is to rate limit any specific **user/bot** which is sending multiples request. One solution is to use advanced [cloudfare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/advanced-rate-limiting/) rate limit but its only support IP counting in **core subscription** which we have already but IP counting is not a good solution at all since it can be send from any corporate LAN having multiple users or proxy servers.

While if I go for normal server side solution we have `node` modules like [express-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit) but I still think the user is coming to our server and then we are blocking them.

Not sure if we have any best solution on **cdn level**. Also how can I track a user request uniquely with **IP address which attributes** I can use.

Comment: express-rate-limit already uses the IP address to detect a need for rate limiting.  To keep the request off your server, some proxies can enforce rate limiting - that would be either your own proxy deployment or something your ISP offers with your hosting service.  If you want to see how you track requests by IP address, then just examine the code of express-rate-limit.

Comment: yes but I am avoiding to use IP address even if I go with express-rate-limit and my plan is to use custom key generator 

`const limiter = rateLimit({ keyGenerator: (request, response) => request.ip,})`
but not sure which attributes I can use in combination to identify request uniquely .  @jfriend00

Comment: For programmatic requests to a public API (that doesn't require a credential), IP address or cookie are pretty much your choices for tracking.  And, a cookie can easily be defeated by an attacker (by just not including the cookie).

Comment: The better way to do this is to require a credential for this API and you can use the credential for rate limiting and, if abused, you can withdraw the credential.  That's how sites like Google do things.

Comment: yes you are right, but challenge here is that I cannot enforce credentials on user/customers. Idea is to avoid guest checkout if user exist in shop and display  login since you already have account.

Comment: But, you can set a cookie upon initial engagement and require that cookie for continued operation and use that cookie for tracking.  If you're doing checkout, you must have a cookie anyway that keys to the cart.

Comment: thanks for the solution, I will try and get back to you on this. Just one thing If you were me what you will choose cloudfare cdn or any other to keep server free from any such issues or you will go for on server solutions considering ecommerce store traffic and challenges.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250949/discussion-between-munawar-khan-and-jfriend00).

Comment: I don't know what cloudfare offers in this regard.